# RestSharp DLL file not found

Tags: c#, restsharp

I installed RestSharp 106.2.1 via  Nuget on Visual Studio 2015 for a class library object. The DotNet Framework version is 4.6.1.

When using my DLL, I'm getting an error that 106.2.1.0 is not found. In Visual Studio, the properties of the DLL show it as 106.2.1.0, however, checking the properties in Explorer, it's 106.2.1.1.

I've already tried to manually change the reference in my .csproj file, but that hasn't worked.

Is there somewhere else I can check to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Do you have any binding redirects in your app.config file?

Comment: I'm not using an app.config file.

Comment: Just tried using the binding redirects, they're not working.

Comment: I found the problem and solved it. https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/158228